# Yii custom pattern issue

Tags: php, regex, yii, validationrules

Hello all I am a newbie in the yii framework and i want to validate a textArea that it accepts multiple values in such format "active sports, head gears" comma and space separated. Can any body help me with it that what pattern should be used. with match pattern validation rule any help would be appreciated and Sorry for asking in such nonprofessional mannerism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pattern:

```
'/^\w+((, \w+)?)*$/'
```

Examples:

```
'active sports, head gears' // false
'sports, gears'             // true
', '                        // false
'head'                      // true
```

Comment: this doesn't fit to my need actually i want that user must use a ", " between every word to separate them @Vladimir

Comment: Maybe `'/^(\w+|, )+$/'`.

Comment: Or better `'/^\w+((, \w+)?)*$/'`.

Comment: thanks for your help but i need an other tweak too in this if you can help I'll be very much thankful to you In the examples how to make the first one to be true @Vladimir kovpak

Comment: Try `'/^[\w\s]+((, [\w\s]+)?)*$/'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add into your model rules arary

```
array('Test', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[a-zA-Z0-9]|[,]*$/')
```

Not tested but i'm sure it will work for you.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]|[,]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aixChfkUOg_TBEUZ)

Comment: I have tried this pattern but it is not working for me can you tell me what is happening in this? @Rohit